# Replacing Special Characters in Teradata

Tags: teradata

I have special character in Teradata database, and I want to remove it.

```
Example - special character: "aa€bb"  (special charcter is "€" sign)
Desired output: "aabb"
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Is it always that value or can it be anything that is not considered alphanumeric in the Latin character set? I'm thinking a UDF would be your best bet.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Teradata 14 (and sorry, I don't), you should be able to use the new `REGEXP_REPLACE` function, something like this:

```
SELECT  'aa€bb' as source_col
       , REGEXP_REPLACE(source_col, '€') as new_col1
       , REGEXP_REPLACE(source_col, '€', NULL, 1, 0, 'c') as new_col2
```

The first example should do the trick; the second just shows the other function parameter values and their defaults.  The third parameter is the replacement string, so when null, it should remove that character.